# Diagnosing receiving empty curl response for curl_exec in php

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to post a file and some data using curl to a local go server hosted on the same machine:

```
    // initialise the curl request
    $request = curl_init('http://localhost:9049/api');

    // send a file
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt(
        $request,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
        array(
            'company' => 'compname',
            'user' => 'compuser',
            'srv'=> 0,
            'colTxt' => 'col1|col2|col3',
            'upfile' => '@' . $_FILES['upfile']['tmp_name']
                                    . ';filename=' . $_FILES['upfile']['name']
                                    . ';type=' . $_FILES['upfile']['type']
        ));

    // output the response
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $res = curl_exec($request);

    // close the session
    curl_close($request);
```

Unfortunately the above code is giving an empty response, have tried many various methods, but still an empty response.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$target_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
$result=curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

Even the curl_getinfo($ch) is empty, so it is getting hard to diagnose. Although there doesn't seem to be a network problem as i can post a file using curl from the command line and it worked perfectly fine. Any idea on what i might be missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/class.curlfile.php) for details on using curl to upload files with the curlfile class